# Polymer and Nodejs (express), Stylsheets are loading with wrong MIME

Tags: css, node.js, express, polymer

Today I started diving into Polymer. What I am trying to do is build a simple site using Node and Polymer. For now the goal is to build one like the Starter Kit from scratch to learn the basics.

I have set up a server using Node and express. I use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` to deliver resources. Apart from that sites are rendered using the ejs engine.

The template that gets rendered is copy pasted from the Starter Kit.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Polymor</title>

<!-- 1. Load webcomponents-lite.min.js for polyfill support. -->
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js">
</script>

<!-- 2. Use an HTML Import to bring in some elements. -->
<link rel="import" href="/elements.html">
</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">

<paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
    <div drawer>
        <!-- Drawer Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar id="drawerToolbar">
            <span class="paper-font-title">Menu</span>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <!-- Drawer Content -->
        <paper-menu>
            <a data-route="home" href="/">
                <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>

            <a data-route="users" href="/users">
                <iron-icon icon="info"></iron-icon>
                <span>Users</span>
            </a>

            <a data-route="contact" href="/contact">
                <iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon>
                <span>Contact</span>
            </a>
        </paper-menu>
    </div>

    <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">

        <!-- Main Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
            <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <span class="flex"></span>

            <!-- Toolbar icons -->
            <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>

            <!-- Application name -->
            <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name">Polymer Starter Kit</div>

            <!-- Application sub title -->
            <div class="bottom title">A Subtitle</div>

        </paper-toolbar>
    </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>


  </body>

</html>
```

I would expect this to work properly however some .css files are missing. The error I get in the console reads: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.css".`

The `paper-drawer-panel` itself gets included in the `elements.html` file and is installed. I simply installed all paper and iron elements.

This is the visual I have which i expected to be different by now for the sidebar on the left.
[image]

Since I am new to Polymer I have no clue where to look at to fix this, or maybe I should use a different way to serve public files?

Comment: That console message is not an error, it's only a warning. Polymer sometimes uses HTML Imports to load CSS, and HTML Imports in Blink is expecting documents not `text/css` and Blink complains. It's annoying but harmless.

Comment: That would be cool. But somehow I expected the elements to look different with just this than they do. Adding a screenshot to question...

Comment: There is no default styling for the DOM you are using in your `paper-menu`. You have to load some CSS or add styles yourself to style them. I believe the Kit has these styles in `app-theme.html`